# Cloud Firestore Query - You can only perform equality comparisons on null

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a dynamic Query by storing a value in the Cloud Firestore that represents a minimum Epoch. Let's call this value "filter_value":

[image]

I am successfully reading this value by calling, from `.onStart()`,

```
        mStoreBaseRef.collection("epoch_filter").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot querySnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot z : querySnapshot){
                Epoch epoch = z.toObject(Epoch.class);
                filterEpochValue = (long) epoch.getFilter_value();
                Log.v("X_VALUE", filterEpochValue.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

I have logged the value and confirmed that it has been read successfully.

I then have a collection of Polls that each have an epoch. I want to use the filter variable from above to perform a Query on these polls, based on their respective Epoch, so that I can only view the polls greater than my "filter_value."

[image]

I am querying using the below:

```
        Query queryStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("Polls")
            .whereGreaterThan("epoch", filterEpochValue)
            .orderBy("vote_count");

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Poll> storeOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Poll>()
            .setQuery(queryStore, Poll.class)
            .build();
```

and receiving the following:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Query. You can only perform equality comparisons on null (via whereEqualTo()).
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenx.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.whereGreaterThan(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.troychuinard.fanpolls.Fragment.TrendingFragment.onStart(TrendingFragment.java:181)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2287)
```

Comment: What is the data type of `filterEpochValue`?  What it its value when logged immediately before you build the Query?

Comment: It is logged as the 75000

Comment: As for the type, I would have to check, but I cast to a Long to hopefully compare to what is stored in each poll. Not sure how Firebase renders after it is added.

Comment: To be clear, I'm asking for the log value not as you show it in the Firestore callback, but immediately before you begin to build the query.  I suspect that it's null.

Comment: Just checked, it is indeed null. Trying to figure out why since it is not null within the .addSnapShotListener()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing the rest of your code, but I suspect that you're building your query without waiting for the snapshot listener callback to complete.  The method addSnapshotListener is *asynchronous*, meaning it returns immediately before the results are ready.  You have to plan for this.  That means you should not continue with your query that depends on `filterEpochValue` until that value becomes available.  The first time it becomes available is in your callback, so you should start your query there.

[Please read here](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93) for more information about why Firebase APIs are asynchronous and what to expect from them.

Comment: You are right - that is exactly what is going on. Is there a way to add a completion callback to guarantee the result?

Comment: Or is the callback everything within .onEvent()?

Comment: onEvent *is* the callback.  Do what you need to do in there, or call another function.